# Auto complete combobox box in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

Like noob i try to use jquery-ui auto complete plugin.

And I have few problems, but first is most important.
My combobox is generated in table, lets name that combobox class is combobox1.
Now I want when type some text if I press tab, to go to next input I get first filtered value in list. For example I have combo with list

- Floppy
- CD
- DVD

And I type `C` I would get in list only `CD` but if I press tab with only typed `C`, I want to select CD, but I getting message that nothing found.

When I generate html table in jquery, and combo box.

I access to it with:

```
 $(".tabl tbody").on("change", ".combobox1", function () {}
```

Code inside this work perfect.

But how I select value when part of text is input?

I was try with something like

```
$(".tabl tbody").on("autocomplete", ".combobox1", function () {
     selectFirst: true;
     alert("chek text");
 });
```

But I not get any response.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `autoFocus` option. It's used like this:

```
$( ".tabl tbody" ).autocomplete( "option", "autoFocus", true );
```

Source: [Autocomplete Widget | jQuery UI API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-autoFocus)

Note: there is no `autocomplete` event in Autocomplete, so that will never trigger. Furthermore, there is no option called `selectFirst` either. Have a deeper look at the API Doc linked above.

Comment: Thanx for answer , but I think problem is in `$( ".tabl tbody" ).autocomplete`. because like i say combobos in table. I think i must find way to use `automplete` on combo not on table, I am right?

Comment: it is very difficult to understand what you want to achieve... please edit your original question and include the html code you're using...